# Topologically Equivalent

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Is it possible to have topologically equivalent metrics with different Cauchy sequences? Are there any actual examples? Or do they usually produce the same Cauchy sequences?

Answer (score 8):

On $\Bbb R$, the metric $d(x,y)=|\arctan x-\arctan y|$ defines the same topology on $\Bbb R$ as the standard metric. Under $d$, the sequence given by $x_n=n$ is Cauchy, but of course not under the standard metric.